# how to store values in tempdata mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to store json location value in tempdata, I am getting the user current location by using json api and I want to display the content to user on the base of location but I couldn't be able to do this so I am sharing my code, guys please help me out

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var strip, strcountry, strcity, strregion, strlatitude, strlongitude, strtimezone

        function GetUserInfo(data) {

            strip = data.host; strcountry = data.countryName; strcity = data.city;

            strregion = data.region; strlatitude = data.latitude; strlongitude = data.longitude;

            strtimezone = data.timezone;

        }

        $(function () {

            BindUserInfo();

        })

        function BindUserInfo() {

            //document.getElementById('lblCity').innerText = strcity;
            $('#term').attr("placeholder", strcity);
            $('#term').attr("value", strcity);



        }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=GetUserInfo"></script>
```

now I want to get the location from here and apply in linq query, I am using MVC 4 (Razor) please help me out of this.

Comment: At what point in the server-side code do you want to use this value?  Should it be used in later page loads?  Or do you need to do something with it server-side right away?  The former would involve posting it to the server somehow (which depends entirely on what this page is/does), the latter would involve making an AJAX call to a new action method which runs the server-side code and returns JSON data.

Comment: @David I am using this value on the index action of restaurant controller, I want to display the restaurant list based on the user current location, if u still not got my point then I can share server side code as well..but please help me out

Comment: Well, where does this JavaScript code run in relation to where you need to use the value?  That is, after this JavaScript code runs, what brings the user to the index action of the restaurant controller?

Comment: @David when user clicks on restaurant link the page will display the restaurant list based on the user current location, if there is any alternate method to do this thing then I would be glad

Comment: @David I need to use this value in my restaurant controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, it sounds like this sequence of events is happening:

1. User is on a page which contains this JavaScript code
2. User clicks a link on that page to go to another page
3. The other page needs to display data based on the value from this JavaScript code

If that's correct, then you have a number of options available to you.  To be clear, what is the value in question?  `strcity`?:

```
$('#term').attr("placeholder", strcity);
$('#term').attr("value", strcity);
```

If so, then when you set that value here you could also potentially set it on perhaps the query string for the link to the next page.  Something like this:

```
$('#someLink').src = '@Url.Action("Index", "Restaurants")?city=' + strcity;
```

This would use a mix of pre-run server-side code for the root of the link, and client-side code to just append that one value to it.  Then the controller method simply accepts `city` as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult Index(string city)
{
    // get your list of restaurants and return the view
}
```

There's no need for `TempData` in this, you're just sending the value directly to the controller action.

If for whatever reason you don't want to modify the `src` like that, you could perhaps instead send the value through a form invoked by the link.  So instead of an `ActionLink` to the index action on the restaurants controller, you might have something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Restaurants", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <a id="restaurantsLink" href="javascript:void(0);">Go to restaurants</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="city" />
}
```

And JavaScript code later:

```
$('#restaurantsLink').click(function () {
    $('form').submit();
});
```

You might need to more uniquely identify that form in the jQuery selector, particularly if there are (or could be) other forms on that page.  Then in your original JavaScript code you would just set the value in the hidden input:

```
$('input[name=city]').val(strcity);
```

In this second case the controller action would still be the same as the first one, accepting a `city` string parameter.

Comment: I have follow your method but I am getting error here "            var model = db.Restaurants.Where(x => x.RestaurantId != null).Where(x => x.Locations.Select(c => c.City == city)) // here is the error
"

Comment: error is here in this segment ".Where(x => x.Locations.Select(c => c.City == city))" the error is "cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic.ienumerable<bool> to bool"

Comment: @user2755609: The logic in your LINQ statement is incorrect then.  It's unrelated to the question, but what seems to be happening is that you're selecting a list of `bool` values to use in a `Where` clause, which needs a `bool` value (not a list of them).  I'm mostly guessing since I don't know your data, but it sounds like you might want something like: `.Where(x => x.Locations.Any(c => c.City == city))`  This would result in a `bool` which is `true` if *any* of the locations match the city, and `false` if none of them match.

Comment: thanks it worked, but I tried this "            $('#link').src = '@Url.Action(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Restaurant")?city=' + strcity;
" and got this link which is not working "http://localhost:1985/Restaurant?Length=10"

Comment: @user2755609: Where did `"Length=10"` come from?  In the view, does it looks like the `?` and characters after it are part of the server-side code?  If so, try: `$('#link').src = '@Url.Action(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Restaurant")' + '?city=' + strcity;`  That would separate the client-side content from the server-side code a little more.

Comment: thankyou so much man!! it worked, please give me some professional jquery and ajax learning resources only if u can :)

Comment: @user2755609: Honestly, practice is your best resource :)  John Resig has a book or two that he's published, I haven't read his work but I doubt you'd find a better source on jQuery expertise than him.  Of course, I don't think his work would have any focus on how to make this work inside of ASP.NET MVC views seamlessly, which is the bulk of what was happening here.  So just continuing to find and employ new ways of doing things is your best bet there.  The main thing to understand is the separation of client-side and server-side code, and how that creates a specific order of events.